# lift, return, and a transformer type constructor

Tags: haskell, monad-transformers

For well over a year, I have been intensely using `lift`, `return`, and constructors such as `EitherT`, `ReaderT`, and so forth.  I've read Real World Haskell, Learn You a Haskell, almost every monad tutorial out there, and tried writing my own.  Yet, I constantly remain confused about these three operations.  Any time I am writing new code I try to figure out which of the three to use, and it almost always takes me an hour or more on the first function in a particular block of code.

What is an intuitive understanding of the three?  Simple types are insufficient, as in all three cases I can instantly recite the types to you.  What is a meaning for what these *do* that is consistent across all of the standard monad transformers?

(Unfortunately, if you respond in math terms, I'm still not going to understand you.  While I can write code to solve math problems and can set up time complexity based on the code I see, I cannot after many years of trying to work in Haskell relate math terms to programming terms.)

Comment: If you know their types, what's the problem? They do what their types say they do. I'm not being mean here, I'm honestly 100% incomprehending. It's like asking when you should use a function with a type `Int -> Bool` versus a function with a type `String -> Bool`. You use the one that matches the type you need.

Comment: I would focus on understanding each of `lift`, `return`, and various constructors in isolation.  There is no thread that links them all together that will provide deeper insight than you will get from understanding each one on its own.  This should really be three separate questions for how to understand each one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So let's say you have a computation. In a lazy language like Haskell you'd write

```
comp1 :: a
```

and know that this computation will be performed upon request and result in a value of type `a`.

---

Let's say you have a similar computation, but in addition to computing a value of type `a`, it might "fail" for some reason or another. For example, `a` might be `Integer` and this computation will "fail" if its a division by zero. We're write this now as

```
comp2 :: Maybe a
```

where the `Maybe` constructor "tags" the `a` to indicate failure.

---

Let's say we have a similar computation as before, but now we are allowed to fail, but also collect a log during the computation. "Log collecting" is called `Writer` so we'd like to tag our type with `Writer` as well as `Maybe`. Unfortunately

```
comp3_bad :: (Writer String) Maybe a
```

doesn't make any sense. The definition of writer allows for a single parameter, not two. We can consider a bit of what the underlying mechanics of this combined effect would be, though—it needs to return a `Maybe` paired with the log... or perhaps if the computation fails, the log is discarded. There are two options

```
comp3_1 :: (String, Maybe a)
comp3_2 :: Maybe (String, a)
```

If we unpack the `Writer`, we can see that these are equivalent to

```
comp3_1' :: Writer String (Maybe a)
comp3_2' :: Maybe (Writer String a)
```

This pattern of nesting is called composition. If you want to combine the effects of two monads then you'd like to compose them. For some monads this works directly, though it's a little cumbersome.

Unfortunately, some monads start to break the monad laws once they are composed. They can still be "stacked" but not in the normal way. So, we allow each type to determine its stacking method by creating the transformer version `<monad>T`.

```
newtype WriterT w m a = WriterT { runWriterT :: m (w, a) }
newtype MaybeT m a    = MaybeT { runMaybeT :: m (Maybe a) }

-- note that

WriterT String Maybe a == Maybe (String, a)
MaybeT (Writer String) a == (String, Maybe a)
```

These composed stacks of monads are called monad transformer stacks and they allow you to assemble side effects in layers.

---

So what happens if we have two different, but similar stacks that we'd like to use together. For instance, we can consider `Maybe` to be a monad... or a monad transformer stack of a single layer. Compare that to `WriterT String Maybe` which is a monad transformer stack of two layers, the bottom of which is `Maybe`.

These two stacks are very similar, but we cannot transport computations from one to the other. Or rather, we can, but it's fairly annoying

```
transport :: Maybe a -> WriterT String Maybe a
transport Nothing  = WriterT Nothing
transport (Just a) = WriterT (Just ("", a))
```

this `transport` forms a general pattern where we "add another layer" onto a stack. This general pattern is called `lift`

```
lift :: Maybe a -> WriterT String Maybe a
```

Or, written polymorphically we see the extra layer `t` being prepended.

```
lift :: MonadTrans t => m a -> t m a
```

---

Finally, we've come a long way from our pure computation at the beginning

```
comp1 :: a
```

and demonstrated that we can `lift` simple transformer stacks into more complex ones. Can we consider `comp1` to be living in the very simplest of transformer stacks—the empty stack?

It turns out that this is actually a really valid point of view. We can even "lift" `comp1` into a more sophisticated transformer stack... but the terminology changes slightly.

```
return :: Monad m => a -> m a
```

So, it's valid to think of `return` as lifting a pure computation into a basic monad. This is a foundational principle of monads even—that they can embed pure computations within them.

Comment: In essence, `return` works to bring a value/computation into a monadic context, and `lift` does the same thing, except by wrapping a monadic value around another?  That's the intuition I'm getting from you and from Daniel Wagner.

Comment: Yep, that's basically the idea. You can start at the bottom of a "stack" and lift things all the way to the top. You can also see the whole stack as a monad and `return` them directly to the top.

Answer (score 6):

- `return` takes a pure computation and turns it into a computation which claims to have some monad-y side-effects, but doesn't.
- `lift` takes a computation that has *some* side-effects, and adds more.
- `EitherT`, `ReaderT`, and so on take a computation that already has all the side-effects you're interested in and "spells them differently" -- for example, where before your state was spelled as a function that returns an updated value, it is now spelled as a `State(T)`-ful computation.